# ifelse condition in RStudio, substituting the values of a column to another

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to do something like the following in my coding:

I have 3 variables (x, y, z) in my dataframe df. I want to create a new variable w, where it will be first populated with x if the value of x is not 1 or 2, however if x is 1 or 2, then w will be populated by y iff y is not 1 or 2, and lastly if y is 1 or 2, then w will take the value of z.

So I wrote the following..

```
df$w <- ifelse((df$x!=1 | df$x!=2), df$x, 
                   ifelse((df$y!=1 | ds$y!=2), df$y, df$z))
```

But, this does not seem to work, the variable w takes the value of x but after that fails to go to y and check the condition and proceed to z.
I have tried a few other techniques but no matter how I tweak this, it doesn't work!

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Please point out to me if this is a duplicate question, though I could not find anything close (I may be totally off track with my searching skills!).

Comment: The code looks alright to me, giving a reproducible example may be more helpful in diagnosing your issue.

Comment: I think you might be intending to use `&` not `|`. i.e. `df$w <- ifelse((df$x!=1 & df$x!=2), df$x, 
                   ifelse((df$y!=1 & ds$y!=2), df$y, df$z))`

Comment: Thanks for this @Mosquite. I thought of the & but the logic of it was not sitting well with me... anyway I tried that too. But didn't work as well. I will check once again.

Comment: Hi @zack.. I will try to post a reproducible example soon ... Thanks for confirming about the code though.

Comment: Hi @Mosquite I ran my code again with your corrections and seems that is the right way to go. Not sure why previously it didn't give me the right results....! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Zack, not giving a reproducible e.g. as this solves it! Thanks again!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Thank you very much @Mosquite